# What does IB mean in IBAction, IBOutlet, etc..?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am very new to iPhone development. I often encounter `IBAction`, `IBOutlet` and so on when reading Objective-C and Swift code. What does `IB` stand for?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"Interface Builder".

Before Xcode 4, the interface files (XIBs and NIBs) were edited in a separate program called Interface Builder, hence the prefix.

`IBAction` is defined to `void`, and `IBOutlet` to nothing. They are just clues to Interface Builder when parsing files to make them available for connections.

Just to add the reference, inside AppKit/NSNibDeclarations.h you'll find these:

```
#ifndef IBOutlet
#define IBOutlet
#endif

#ifndef IBAction
#define IBAction void
#endif
```

So, actually, code like this:

```
@interface ...
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

Will be transformed into:

```
@interface ...
{
     NSTextField *label;
}
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

By the preprocessor, even before the compiler sees it. Those keywords were acting just as clues to Interface Builder.

Comment: Just to add up, the `IBAction` is `void`. It's sort of a markup thing so that Interface Builder would see which methods code exposes for connections to buttons and other controls. Not sure about `IBOutlet`, but I'm sure it's similar to `IBAction` so that Interface Builder would see what controls it can connect to the code as well.

Comment: The tool is still called Interface Builder; it just no longer exists as a separate app. Shame, because I really adore the icon.

Comment: @Eimantas I've been editing the answer to make a note in these at the same time you were writing the comment :-) thanks for pointing it too

Comment: @BoltClock I still have its icon in the dock. It has been there for years, side-by-side with Xcode :-)

Comment: In Swift code, I see @IBOutlet weak var = ... What's the meaning of the @ sign?

Answer (score 6):

IB stands for interface builder, as you connect objects via the interface builder .

Answer (score 3):

IBAction and IBOutlet are interface Builder Constants
IBOutlet:A Controller class can refer to the object in the nib file using a special constant called IBOutlet.

IBActions:Interface objects in the nib file can be set to trigger specific methods in controller class using IBAction as return type of the method.