# Are empty macro definitions allowed in C? How do they behave?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose the "empty" macro definition

```
#define FOO
```

Is it valid Standard C? If so, what is `FOO` after this definition?

Comment: It is empty string, and yes, it is acceptable.

Comment: Just to point out, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8592056/557306) another question which involves an interesting use of empty defines.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It is simply a macro that expands to, well, nothing. However, now that the macro has been defined you can check with `#if defined` (or `#ifdef`) whether it has been defined.

```
#define FOO

int main(){
    FOO FOO FOO
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

will expand to

```
int main(){

    printf("Hello world");
}
```

There are certain situations where this comes in very handy, for example additional debug information, which you don't want to show in your release version:

```
/* Defined only during debug compilations: */
#define CONFIG_USE_DEBUG_MESSAGES

#ifdef CONFIG_USE_DEBUG_MESSAGES
#define DEBUG_MSG(x) print(x)
#else
#define DEBUG_MSG(x) do {} while(0)
#endif

int main(){
    DEBUG_MSG("Entering main");
    /* ... */
}
```

Since the macro `CONFIG_USE_DEBUG_MESSAGES` has been defined, `DEBUG_MSG(x)` will expand to `print(x)` and you will get `Entering main`. If you remove the `#define`, `DEBUG_MSG(x)` expands to an empty `do`-`while` loop and you won't see the message.

Comment: This is very risky, since it can break compilation esp. when you have statements like ```if (x) DEBUG_MSG("test"); else DEBUG_MSG("test");```. I prefer to declare my empty macro with an no-effect statement like ```#define DEBUG_MSG(x) do {} while(0)```

Comment: @Ely Why would that break? If `DEBUG_MSG` was defined as `#defined DEBUG_MSG(x)` then `else DEBUG_MSG("test")` just becomes `else ;` which is valid because `;` is the 'empty statement'.

Comment: I sometimes do something like that: `#define NOTHING` Then stuff like `int NOTHING main()`

Comment: @Ely Why would that break?  Why not just `{}`?

Comment: But in the real world, Log functions have variadic parameters `DEBUG_MSG("message %s %s %s", parameters, and, more);`. It is still compatible with such syntax, or do we have to take care or the parameters which have to be wiped with the function on Release mode?

Comment: @Sandburg it's compatible, and the same holds, e.g. you can use `#define DEBUG_MSG(fmt, ...)` and keep the definition empty.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, empty define is allowed by the standard.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.10 Preprocessing directives**
>
> ```
> control-line:
>    # define identifier replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen identifier-list(opt) ) replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
>    # define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
> replacement-list:
>     pp-tokens(opt)
> ```

A common utilisation is inclusion guards.

```
#ifndef F_H
# define F_H

#endif
```

Comment: You haven't answer what is value of `FOO` after empty define.

Comment: @user14284 Macros don't have values. They expand to a list of tokens. This list can be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Empty macro definitions can also be used for self-documentation. The `IN` in the code snippet below is a sample. The code and the comment are both quoted from the [EDK II project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edk2/).

```
//
// Modifiers for Data Types used to self document code.
// This concept is borrowed for UEFI specification.
//

///
/// Datum is passed to the function.
///
#define IN


typedef
EFI_STATUS
(EFIAPI *EFI_BLOCK_RESET)(
  IN EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL          *This,
  IN BOOLEAN                        ExtendedVerification
  );
```

Comment: I would use another example. It doesn't have to be a quote from actual code, but the current example contains a rather large amount of unnecessary information. (By the way, make sure that your answer still answers the original question; it works well with the other answers, but as a standalone answer, it doesn't really fit the question "What does `FOO` expand to"?).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just happen to be reading this piece of code when see this question. Since the answer has long been chosen, I just hope my reply can serve as some educative reference.