# If #define is used without any assignment value, what will it do?

Tags: c++

`#define TML_ID`  -   No value is assigned to TML_ID. There's no problem in compilation or building executables. will this assign any default value like null to TML_ID or will TML_ID be considered undefined ?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't have a value? What about an empty string?

Comment: [C duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892191/empty-macro-definition-in-c), same answer in C++.

Answer (score 7):

This simply says that the macros *is defined*, so you can do this in `main` or any other function:

```
#ifdef TML_ID
printf("Defined!\n");
#else
printf("Undefined!\n");
#endif
```

Comment: `#endif` (had to)

Comment: @qxz, yep, I forgot that, thanks for pointing out. Edited now.

Comment: Thanks. yes, it's considered defined even if no value is assigned to it.

Comment: @ForceBru Before compilation C preprocessor will expand the macro, replacing their textual appearances with their values. If a macro is defined w/o value, like other answers said, their values will be garbage (undefined), in such case how does preprocessor know which value to substitute?

Comment: @torez233, none of the other answers said that their values will be garbage. If a macro has no value, the use of this macro will be simply deleted (that use will be replaced with nothing).

Comment: @ForceBru yes you're right, I misunderstood the other answers. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

`#define` doesn't assign a value to the macro. In fact, it's considered as a flag to tell the compiler that a specific macro has been defined.

You can imagine it as if you declare a variable without assigning any values. It will have a garbage value but it will reserve a space in the memory. But in case of a macro, the definition won't reserve a space. Only a hint for the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: A macro without any replacement text does not have a garbage value.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's correct, that's why i used the term "flag". That's also a difference between a defined-less macro and an unused variable.

Answer (score 1):

Without assigned a value, macros in this way are usually used to prevent including same .h file multiple times, this way:

```
#ifndef _FILENAME
#define _FILENAME

//declaration code

#endif
```

If some .cpp file includes, for example, two different .h files, which both include our .h file, then .cpp will have only one copy of declaration code, since second time _FILENAME macro will be DEFINED, and declaration code will be skipped.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_FILENAME`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MACRO
```

defines a macro named MACRO. It has no content, so if you wrote something like `std::cout << MACRO` you'd get an error because there's nothing there. This is often used to conditionally use new keywords:

```
#if CPP_VERSION_C11
    #define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
    #define NOEXCEPT
#endif

void f() NOEXCEPT {
    // whatever
}
```

There are two other ways you can use such a macro. You can check whether it's defined:

```
#ifdef MACRO
    // code for one branch
#else
    // code for other branch
#endif
```

For that code, since `MACRO` has been defined, the preprocessor will look at the code in the first branch, and skip the code in the second branch. If `MACRO` had not been defined, it would skip the code in the first branch rather than the second. You can also do the same thing this way:

```
#if defined(MACRO)
```

or you can use it in a constant expression in a preprocessor directive:

```
#if MACRO
    // code for one branch
#else
    // code for other branch
#endif
```

here, `MACRO` gets the value 0, the `#if` sees the value 0, and the preprocessor skips the first branch. The same thing occurs in more complex expressions:

```
#if MACRO + 1 > 0
    // code for one branch
#else
    // code for other branch
#endif
```

Here, `MACRO` has the value 0, `MACRO + 1` has the value 1, and the first branch will be selected.

Comment: Re: "here, MACRO gets the value 0, the #if sees the value 0". In case anyone's wondering, this behaviour is a corollary of section 6.10.1 of the C standard. (same section in all three of C99, C11 and C17.)